# Get camera display in runtime objective C

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, camera, avfoundation

I want to get camera display in runtime, without taking picture.  I mean something like when you add `UIImagePickerController` and then take picture in `NSTimer` method: `- (void) timerMethod{ [picker takePicture]; }`
Is this possible in iOS SDK?

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're asking.  Do you want to display a video of what the camera is seeing without taking any pictures?

Comment: Yes, but I don't want to display the "video." I want to display the representation which takes camera.

Comment: Well there is something called AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer that you can use to display what is seen by the camera in real time. If that is what you are asking?

Comment: Yes man! Exactly! That's what I wanted.
Thank you so much @Sredni . Please post it as answer so I can accept it and give you a reputation.
Thanks again :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` is the name of the game :)